# FireStore - TypeError: k.setTimeout is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase in a React Native app and authentication with a facebook token. It works fine with RealTime Database.
But not Firestore. When I call collection.get, set or add I got this error which is not caught by my handler but just dumped in the console.

> (node:15795) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: k.setTimeout is not a function

I tried also as a standalone script run as `node t_firebase.js`.

I installed the packages with

```
npm install firebase
npm install firestore
```

I'm using node v6.11.4 and npm 3.10.10, firestore 1.1.6, firebase 4.5.1

Here is the script:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");

var config = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "....firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://....firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

testFirebase();

function testFirebase(){
  console.log("testFirebase");
  token="...";
  var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);

  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
  .then(function(val){testFirestore();})
  .catch((error)=>{console.log("error:"+error);});
}


function testFirestore(){
  console.log("testFirestore");
  var db = firebase.firestore();
  var collection = db.collection("livros");

  var docref = collection.add({
    autor: "AdaLovelace",
    name: "blabla"
  }).then(function(val){ console.log("OK"); }).catch((error)=>{console.log("error:"+error);});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you mention React Native, your error is actually from node.js so I'm not certain which environment you're asking about.

- **React Native** - The "firebase" npm module does not currently work with React Native due to a bug. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/183 for more details and workarounds.
- **Node.JS** - You can use Cloud Firestore from Node.JS using the "firebase-admin" SDK. See the node.js snippets on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart for more details. Cloud Firestore is not currently supported via the "firebase" SDK, but this is planned in the future.  See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/221 for more details.